# Handle malformed HTML (no closing tags)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, lxml

I use BeautifulSoup to parse HTML via `lxml` parser. But i encountered a file which doesn't have ANY closing tags inside a `<table>`:

```
<table id='reportTable' class='report-table' style='width:auto' cellspacing='0'><tr>
<th>Номер<br>поезда<th>Дата<br>отправления<th>Маршрут<th>Причина<th>Комментарий<th>Станция ...
```

Though the `<table>` tag is properly closed.

Comment: Did you already try to parse it without success? Half the point of an html parser is that it can tolerate badly formed html just like a browser would. Missing closing tags should not present an issue

Comment: @C.Feenstra it recognizes some `td`s but often fails to split. I'll try to make a sample file later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I have come across this problem myself and  I run the whole document through HTMLTidy 5 using tidylib. Saying that I agree with C. Feenstra lxml parser can tolerate malformed html. If you have got html that you really can't parse with lxml parser then try this:

```
from tidylib import tidy_document

badHtml = "<table id='reportTable' class='report-table' style='width:auto' cellspacing='0'><tr><th>Номер<br>поезда<th>Дата<br>отправления<th>Маршрут<th>Причина<th>Комментарий<th>Станция ..."
options = {"output-bom": 0, "quiet": False, "word-2000": True,
           "output-encoding": 'utf8', "output-xhtml": 1, "add-xml-decl": 0,
           "tidy-mark": 0, "drop-proprietary-attributes": True,
           "show-warnings": False, }
tidiedHtml, errors = tidy_document(badHtml, options)
```

Then use "tidiedHtml" for BeautifulSoup

Comment: That works, thanks! I've installed `pytidylib` and also `tidy.dll` from http://binaries.html-tidy.org My input encoding is `cp1251` so i had to pre-encode raw data to `utf-8`